# Greater than or equal for floats failed

Tags: python, floating-accuracy, floating

I was running a small python test I wrote against some data and got some weird results.  Boiled it down to this:

```
priceDiff = 219.92 - 219.52
if(priceDiff >= .40):
   print "YES"
else:
   print "NO"
```

---

The result is "NO"

Why is 0.40 not >= .40?

Comment: Try `print(219.92 - 219.52)`. You will be surprised.

Comment: I tried float.hex(priceDiff) and float.hex(.40), yes I'm surprised although i suppose I should be.  Been a while since I've had to wrangle floating point numbers but I just assumed this would work (since I was just comparing data that contained prices)

Comment: You don't have to go that far. `priceDiff` is 0.39999999999997726, which is less than .4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: "Never test floating-point numbers for equality". In this case one option might be to code a little bit of wriggle-room, setting the boundary at a value that has less significance and might be "impossible", such as `priceDiff >= 0.3995` (or `0.39999995`). For complete predictability and accuracy, use Decimal not float.

Comment: When working with prices it is advised to use integer number of cents internally, to prevent these kind of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python offers controlled environment to work with floats in the form of  "[**Decimal**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html)". It provides multiple options to control/tweak the rounding with amount of rounding along with different strategies.(https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes).

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_EVEN
a = Decimal(219.92).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
b = Decimal(219.52).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
priceDiff = a - b
cmp = Decimal(0.40).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN)

if priceDiff.compare(cmp) >= 0:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"

print(d)
print(d2)
print(priceDiff)
print(cmp)
```

IMHO this is better interms of readability and implementaion of calculations that are precision sensitive w.r.t application. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

From Documentation

> Representation error refers to the fact that some (most, actually) decimal 
>   fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary (base 2) fractions.
>   This is the chief reason why Python (or Perl, C, C++, Java, Fortran,
>   and many others) often won’t display the exact decimal number you
>   expect:

```
0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```